# Is there a way to apply acl to CiviMail's mass mailings?

Tags: civimail, acl

My collegues need to hide some sensitive mails in mailings list and activities by acl persmissions. Default users shouldn't have access to mailings assigned to role "Chief staff".

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users shouldn't be able to see mailings if they don't have access to the groups that the mailings are to.  Note that this was broken not too long ago, so make sure you're using a newer version; see [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13644); also relevant is [this](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16981) and [this](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17400), which help if someone saves a draft of a sensitive mailing without specifying a group.

Also, note [this patch](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18159), which is a related but different issue, and hasn't been merged into core yet.